# AJAX -> PHP not updating MySQL database consistently

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, ajax

So this is my early attempt at a Facemash style site in which the user will select one of two images, scoring a hit with the chosen image (the winner) and a miss with the unselected image (the loser) - both of which are recorded in a MySQL database.

The selected image is determined using javascript and uses jquery AJAX to notify a PHP script (backend.php) which updates the database.

This works absolutely correctly for updating the "hits" field. However, the "misses" are not consistently recorded. By this I mean that when the user clicks one image, the fact the other image has not been clicked is only *sometimes* shown in the database. As far as I can tell there is no pattern as to when the "miss" is and is not recorded, making it difficult to pinpoint where the problem lies.

I've checked the code over and over again and cannot understand why this is happening or what would be responsible for it, so I thought it would be best to post everything. I appreciate it's a lot to ask, but any explaination as to why I'm having this problem would be hugely appreciated, thanks.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Facemash</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
// Make a MySQL Connection
mysql_connect("localhost", "admin", "admin") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("facemash") or die(mysql_error());

// Select two random people
$personA = rand(1, 28);
$personB = rand(1, 28);

// Ensure that it is not the same person
if ($personB == $personA) {
   $personB = rand(1, 28);
}

// Function to return path of photo
function photoPath ($person){

$query = mysql_query("SELECT photo FROM people WHERE id=$person");
$result  = mysql_fetch_row($query);
$result = $result[0];

echo $result;
}
?>

<!--Image for personA-->
<div id=photoA identity="<?php echo $personA ?>"><img src="<?php photoPath($personA);?>"/></div>

<!--Image for personB-->
<div id=photoB identity="<?php echo $personB ?>"><img src="<?php photoPath($personB);?>"/></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#photoA').click(function() {
        var hit = $('#photoA[identity]').attr('identity');
        var miss = $('#photoB[identity]').attr('identity');
        $.post ("backend.php", {winner: hit} );
        $.post ("backend.php", {loser: miss} );
        location.reload(true);
    });

    $('#photoB').click(function() {
        var hit = $('#photoB[identity]').attr('identity');
        var miss = $('#photoA[identity]').attr('identity');
        $.post ("backend.php", {winner: hit} );
        $.post ("backend.php", {loser: miss} );
        location.reload(true);
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

backend.php:

```
<?php
    // Make a MySQL Connection
    mysql_connect("localhost", "admin", "admin") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("facemash") or die(mysql_error());

    // Recieve id of winner from index.php
    $winner = $_POST['winner'];
    // Recieve id of loser from index.php
    $loser = $_POST['loser'];

    // Lookup hits for winner and update by adding 1
    function updateHits ($winner) {
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT hits FROM people WHERE id=$winner");
    $result  = mysql_fetch_row($query);
    $result = $result[0];

    $result++;

    mysql_query("UPDATE people SET hits = $result WHERE id=$winner");
    }

    //Lookup misses for loser and update by adding 1
    function updateMisses ($loser) {
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT misses FROM people WHERE id=$loser");
    $result  = mysql_fetch_row($query);
    $result = $result[0];

    $result++;

    mysql_query("UPDATE people SET misses = $result WHERE id=$loser");
    }

    updateHits($winner);
    updateMisses($loser);
?>
```

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple things.

```
// Select two random people
$personA = rand(1, 28);
$personB = rand(1, 28);

// Ensure that it is not the same person
if ($personB == $personA) {
   $personB = rand(1, 28);
}
```

This doesn't look like it will always guarantee they aren't the same person. The result of the second rand() could again return the same value as $personA

Instead of doing two queries to first select the misses and then increment it, why not make it one query?:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE people SET misses = misses + 1 WHERE id=$loser");
```

Lastly, in backend.php, instead of updating winners and losers even if you have only received one of the params, do an if else:

```
if($winner) {
  updateHits($winner);
} else if ($loser) {
  updateMisses($loser);
}
```

I think this will solve your problems.

As a matter of optimization, you should also combine your two POSTs into one.

Comment: Thanks, this combined with mofle's answer seem to have done it (although I think the change to the query did it). I didn't use the if statement, however, as both hits and misses needed to be updated. Thanks again for all the help. :)

Comment: Gotcha, ok. It looks like since you are sending the params winner and loser in separate requests, you never are running both the updateHits and updateMisses at the same time.

Comment: @Josh, what's strange is that his query is exactly the same as mine and you said that mine didn't work.  But Vibhu was right on all of his comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your two functions to this and seeing if it will work.  (If it doesn't I will just delete my answer.)

```
    // Lookup hits for winner and update by adding 1
    function updateHits ($winner) {
    mysql_query("UPDATE `people` SET `hits` = hits + 1 WHERE `id`= '$winner'");
    }

    //Lookup misses for loser and update by adding 1
    function updateMisses ($loser) {
    mysql_query("UPDATE `people` SET `misses` = misses + 1 WHERE `id` = '$loser'");
    }
```

Comment: No, same problem unfortunately. Out of 10 hits only 6 misses were recorded :(

Answer (score 0):

This probably doesn't cause the problem, but you should only do one $.post and don't duplicate the same functionality in both click handlers.

JS:

```
$('#photoA, #photoB').click(function() {
    var hit = $('#photoA[identity]').attr('identity'),
        miss = $('#photoB[identity]').attr('identity');
    $.post("backend.php", { winner: hit, loser: miss } );
    location.reload(true);
});
```